# ListView Only Loading One Item

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I came here because I've got a bit of a problem. I'm working with C# using .NET 4.0 & Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7

I'm working on creating a simple Terraria save syncing utility for myself (I may release later once it's more refined) but basically the way it should work is by automatically copying files over to the Dropbox sync directory and then being able to access that same directory on the remote computer, however, I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

I have 4 ListViews all set to detail view. I have 2 list views for the local players and worlds and 2 for the Dropbox players and worlds. What I need these ListViews to do is to display the file names of all the files ending in .plr (for players) or .wld (for worlds). And I have it partially working, but it only shows 1 item!

[image]

As you can see, I have multiple files in the directory but only one happens to be showing up. Here is the code I've used

```
private void loadLocalPlayers()
        {
            string tDir = mr.Read("TERRARIADIR");
            string playersDir = tDir + @"\Players";

            MessageBox.Show("Dir is " + playersDir.ToString());
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(playersDir);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.plr");
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                //lvi.SubItems[0] = file.Name;
                string s = file.Name.ToString();
                char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
                lvi.Text = s;


            }
            localPlayers.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

It reads the directory from a string written to the registry (the directory turns out right) but what I feel is a but fuzzy is the foreach statement, if you guys could help me out I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Your `..Items.Add` probably needs to be inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed your localPlayers.Items.Add method outside the foreachloop.

```
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            lvi = new ListViewItem();
            string s = file.Name.ToString();
            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            lvi.Text = s;

            localPlayers.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

Do this instead

Comment: nope, didnt seem to work :( EDIT: nevermind! saw the declaration of lvi after the fact and moved it into there. that worked, thank you very much!

Comment: It wasn't letting me before, I just now remembered to. Thank you again! :)